# Как и когда произносить "е" или "ё"?

Tags: фонетика

Почему печатают "е", когда произносится "ё"? Например, в поэме Пушкина:

> И сердце "бьется" в упоенье,
>   И для него воскресли вновь
>   И божество, и вдохновенье,
>   И жизнь, и "слезы", и любовь.

И в другом:

> Вам слово молвить, и потом
>   "Все" думать, думать об одном

В песне Окуджавы

> Пока земля "еще" вертится, ... Я знаю - ты "все" умеешь,

В другой песне

> Восторг любви нас "ждет" с тобою...

Ошибка, опечатка?

Как узнать, когда происносится ё?

gentil-coquelicot

Answer (score 1):

женти-коклико,

С произношением буквы Ё частенько путаются даже носители русского языка.
На письме Ё обязательно к применению только в трёх случаях. В именах собственных (и то не всегда), для снятия омонимии (как раз случай "всё" и "все", "ведро" и "вёдро" и т.д.), в изданиях для детей и учебных для иностранцев. В остальных случаях Ё обычно заменяется на Е. Вам же, вероятно, придётся сверяться с орфоэпическим словарем.

Конкретно по вашим примерам. 
~1. У Окуджавы в обоих случаях - *всё*. Вс*е* там грамматически невозможно. Но по правилам всё должно писаться через ё, если в ваших изданиях е, то это либо умышленная вольность, либо ошибка корректора.
~2. С Пушкиным сложнее. Во-первых, произношенние в части Е и Ё сильно изменилось. Некоторые слова во времена Пушкина читались через Е, сейчас - через Ё, а иногда (редко, правда) и наоборот. Во-вторых, в стихах часто применялся так называемый "высокий стиль". Одним из признаков которого было неприменение буквы е. Сравните у того же Пушкина:

*Исчез властитель осужд**е**нный,

Могучий баловень побед,

И для изгнанника вселенной

Уже потомсто наста**е**т.*
("Наполеон")

Здесь в обоих случаях приходится произносить Е из-за рифмы, хотя по орфоэпическим нормам тут Ё. Пушкин этим "высоким стилем" как бы возвращался к фонетическим нормам XVI-XVII веков, подчеркивая эпичность стиха.

Answer (score 0):

Если уж ссылаться на классиков, то позволю себе привести ещё один пример из Пушкина:

Я вас любил безмолвно, безнад**е**жно,
То робостью,то ревностью томим. 
Я вас любил так искренно, так нежно,
Как дай вам бог любимой быть другим

Comment: Плохой пример. Во всяком случае - непонятный без комментария. Перед шипящими Ё во времена Пушкина скорее всего  не было вовсе. Оно и сейчас там редкость. Промежность, успешный, кромешный и т.д. (это слова не на ять, так что речь идёт об исконном Е).

Answer (score 0):

> Почему печатают "е", когда произносится "ё"?

Disclaimer - не столько для автора вопроса, сколько для всяких знатоков.  Ниже я пишу о звуке "ё". Я вполне осведомлён, что официально считается, будто звука "ё" нет, а есть мягкая согласная, после которой следует звук "о".  Я предпочитаю верить своим ушам: в слове лён гласная звучит не так, как буква "о".  Можно и произнести нейотированное ё, отличное от о.

А теперь к делу.

В древнерусском языке звука "ё" изначально не было.  Те слова, которые произносятся через ё, тогда произносились через е.  Постепенно произошёл так называемый "переход е в о".  Начало этого процесса датируется концом XII века, конец - XVI веком.  Звук "е" под ударением после мягких согласных (в том числе шипящих, которые все тогда были мягкими) превратился в звук "ё".  Но это произношение считалось простонародным, малограмотным и так далее.  Постепенно, однако, оно становилось всё более распространённым, и Карамзин в 1783 уже предложил ввести специальную новую букву ё.  Взял он эту букву из французского алфавита, что неудивительно: в то время дворяне (по крайней мере столичные) хорошо знали два языка - русский и французский.

Мало кто захотел писать по-карамзински.  Произношение ё было всё же разговорным, а высоким стилем говорили через е. И литературы, как считалось, должны писать через е.  Анализ рифм показывает, что 200 лет назад современное ё в стихах произносилось как е, кроме некоторых шуточных стихотворений.  Если хочется читать вслух стихи Пушкина так, как их бы читал сам Пушкин, надо всегда читать е.

После революции в СССР произношение "ё" стало единственной нормой. Но орфографические нормы не стали подстраивать под произношение. Согласно сайту gramota.ru, написание ё факультативно.  На практике, в книгах (кроме словарей и т.п.) и журналах почти всегда пишут "е".

Answer (score -1):

Добавлю, что буква Ё не является исконно-русской. Ни в старорусском, ни в церковнославянском языках ее не было (например, говорилось не "сёстры", а "сестры" и т.д.). Привнес же букву Ё в русский язык Карамзин, пользуясь аналогией с аналогичной французской буквой. Позже, реформой А.В. Луначарского Ё, наряду с другими "ненужными" буквами, была упразднена из алфавита, и вернулась туда в году Второй мировой войны. В настоящее время в полиграфическом тексте Ё считается недопустимой.

Comment: Мне кажется, вы несколько перегибаете палку.   
Я не говорю сейчас о случаях обязательного употребления Ё.  
Именно о тексте в целом в полиграфических текстах. Так вот, насколько знаю (а при случае и постараюсь уточнить), сейчас действует правило, допускающее использование Ё при условии обязательного использования по всему тексту. Т.е. либо весть текст без Ё (кроме оговорённых случаев), лиюо тогда уже Ё везде.

Comment: Я, кстати, стараюсь использовать именно последний вариант, особенно на лингвистических форумах. Их часто читаю иностранцы и люди, не вполне владеющие тонкостями Е/Ё. Поэтому Ё здесь не лишне. Но, увы,  иногда забываюсь - и сваливаюст на старыый стиль.